# Vine API Request Returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter, vine

I am trying to pull the JSON data for a Vine via the oEmbed API endpoint created for them. The request works fine in the browser and on my local Vagrant machine, but as soon as I run it on the server, it throws a 500 Internal Server Error. It is as if my Rackspace server has been blocked from making requests to their API, but this is the first time I have ever attempted to make requests to Vine.

```
$url = 'https://vine.co/oembed.json?url=http://vine.co/v/egXzgWMjrTj';
$res = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($res);
```

I have already tried using a cURL request and passing in stream_create_context() with headers into the file_get_contents() call.

My example cURL request that is also returning HTML formatted 500 Internal Server Error

```
$url = 'https://vine.co/oembed.json?url=http://vine.co/v/egXzgWMjrTj';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

My ultimate goal is to get the thumbnail for the video and I am performing similar requests to Vimeo and Instagram without getting an Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

This works, Tested it.

```
$res = file_get_contents('https://vine.co/oembed.json?url=http://vine.co/v/egXzgWMjrTj');
$json = json_decode($res,true);
echo $json['thumbnail_url'];
```

The second parameter of json_decode to true returns an array instead of an object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I the response I get is a 500 Internal Server Error. So, decoding the response as an associative array doesn't actually do me any good.

Comment: Yea I was half asleep when I wrote this so I also missed about the 500 error. Normally though the 500 error is server side. Maybe you should contact your host and see what they say?

Comment: Great, thank you. That is what I am doing right now.